# node alternative to grunt async funciton

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying replace some very old grunt code with some plain node code.

Some functions use `done = this.async()` to give a handle you can use to signify the work is done.

How would I replace this with node code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach may be to use the async/await feature available as of ES2017 / Node.js 7.6. This won't turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous function as the done = this.async() pattern achieves, but it will allow function calls that *look* like they are asynchronous.

One modification that must be made is that the calling function (in this case testGetResult) must be labelled *async*.

For example, let's say you have a function like so:

```
function getResult() {
    var done = this.async();
    asyncCall(function(result) {
        done(result);
    })
}
```

We'd replace with this:

```
function getResult() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        asyncCall(function(result)  {
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
}

/* Example of an asynchronous function called by someFunction. */
function asyncCall(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 1000, { status: 42 } );
}

async function testGetResult() {
    /* Make getResult _look_ like it is synchronous. */
    let result = await getResult();
    console.log('result: ', result);
}

testGetResult();
```

If you were to try to keep the exact syntax you're currently using, I think you'd have to write some pretty funky code to somehow block execution of the function (getResult for example), until the done() function is called.